# How to retype a function in Golang?

Tags: go, reflection, callback

In my current Golang project, I use buffering of logs before sending them to Elasticsearch within my log library. I want to introduce something like C `atexit()` function to flush all pending logs in case of an unexpected exit.

I have found [atexit](https://github.com/tebeka/atexit) library but it was insufficient in my case because it does not allow passing of arguments to handler functions. I decided to write my version and ended up with roughly similar structure. I have module atexit:

```
package atexit

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "reflect"
)

var handlers []interface{}
var params []interface{}

func runHandler(handler interface{}, p interface{}) {
    defer func() {
        if err := recover(); err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "error: atexit handler error:", err)
        }
    }()

    f := reflect.ValueOf(handler)
    s := reflectSlice(p)
    fmt.Printf("%#v", s)
    f.Call(s)
}

func reflectSlice(slice interface{}) []reflect.Value {
    s := reflect.ValueOf(slice)
    if s.Kind() != reflect.Slice {
        panic("InterfaceSlice() given a non-slice type")
    }

    ret := make([]reflect.Value, s.Len())

    for i:=0; i<s.Len(); i++ {
        ret[i] = reflect.ValueOf(s.Index(i))
    }

    return ret
}

func runHandlers() {
    for i, handler := range handlers {
        runHandler(handler, params[i])
    }
}

func Exit(code int) {
    runHandlers()
    os.Exit(code)
}

func Register(handler interface{}, p interface{}) {
    f := reflect.TypeOf(handler)
    if f.Kind() != reflect.Func {
        panic("Register() given a non-function type")
    }
    handlers = append(handlers, handler)
    params = append(params, p)
}
```

and I am calling it from the main program:

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "./atexit"
    "encoding/json"
    "reflect"
)

type Batch struct {
    Index string        `json:"index"`
    Type string     `json:"_Type"`
    Content interface{} `json:"Content"`
}

func flush(b ...interface{}) {
    for _, entry := range(b) {
        fmt.Printf("%#v\n", entry)
        fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(reflect.ValueOf(entry)))
        fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(entry))
        a, err  := json.Marshal(entry)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("error!")
        }
        fmt.Println(string(a))
    }
}

func handler(v ...interface{}) {
    fmt.Println("Exiting")
    for _, batch := range(v) {
        fmt.Printf("%#v\n", batch)
    }
}

func main() {
    type ColorGroup struct {
        ID     int
        Name   string
        Colors []string
    }
    group := ColorGroup{
        ID:     1,
        Name:   "Reds",
        Colors: []string{"Crimson", "Red", "Ruby", "Maroon"},
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", group)
    r, err := json.Marshal(group)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(r))


    b := []Batch{Batch{"index", "type", "content1"},Batch{"index", "type", "content2"}}
    atexit.Register(handler, b)
    atexit.Register(flush, []ColorGroup{group})
    atexit.Exit(0)
}
```

As you can see, by calling `reflect.ValueOf()` I get structure `reflect.Value` which is then passed to callback function. The problem seems to be that this structure does not contain metadata about json export or is not handled correctly with `json.Marshal()`, which then outputs empty json. Is there any way I can pass correct `[]interface{}` structure to the callback function or some similar mechanism which would do roughly what I'm trying to accomplish? Please note that I want a general callback mechanism which should be independent of the type passed to it. So far it seems to be impossible or at least very limited by `f.Call(s)`, which is called in `runHandler()` and takes reflect.Value as its parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not be using reflection for this. You should make your handlers be of type `func()`, then just pass in an anonymous function (possibly a closure) that handles any necessary arguments directly.  Example:

```
atexit.Register(func() {
    handler(b)
})
```